# Javascript add cookie

Tags: javascript, html, string, post, cookies

I am fairly new to javascript and not really sure what I am doing.  Right now I am trying to add textbox data as well as some strings to cookies to display on another page.  The textbox part is working.

For the strings, I am taking the value of a radio button (for a multiple choice quiz validation) and if the value is the correct value for that group, I would like to add a string to cookies.  I can't figure out what I am doing wrong for this part.

Specifically what isn't working is the content in the gradeit() function

JS file

```
var total = 5;
var right = 0;

//cookies
function addToCookie(id, value)
{
  document.cookie = id  + escape(value);

}

var grade=new Array()

function gradeit(){
if(document.getElementById('correctOne').checked)
    {
      right++;
      addToCookie("Q1 - Correct",right);
    }
    else {addToCOokie("Q1 - Incorrect", right);}
}


function checkCookie() {
var firstName = document.getElementById("fname").value;
var lastName = document.getElementById("lname").value;
var email =  document.getElementById("email").value;

    addToCookie("First Name= ",firstName);
    addToCookie("Last Name= ",lastName);
    addToCookie("Email=",email);
 }

window.onload = function () {
var elem = document.getElementById("submit");
elem.addEventListener('click', checkCookie);
}

// determine whether there is a cookie
var allcookies = document.cookie;
alert("All Cookies : " + allcookies);
// Get all the cookies pairs in an array
cookiearray = allcookies.split(';');

var result = "";

// Now take key value pair out of this array
for (var i = 0; i < cookiearray.length; i++) {
  name = cookiearray[i].split('=')[0];
value = cookiearray[i].split('=')[1];
result +=( name + " is : " + value)+"<br>";


 }
document.writeln(result);
```

HTML PAge

```
 <DOCTYPE HTML5>
 <html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Quiz</title>
   <script src="cookies.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1><b>Multiple Choice Quiz</b></h1>
   <form name="myquiz" action="answers.html" method="post">

  <h2>Please Enter the Following:</h2>
    First Name:  <input type="text" id="fname"></input>
    Last Name:   <input type="text" id="lname"></input><br><br> 
    Student Email:   <input type="email" id="email"></input>
<br>
  <h3>#1. What is the capital of Iowa?</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="question1" id="correctOne">Des Moines</input>
    <input type="radio" name="question1" id="wrong">Los Angeles</input>
    <input type="radio" name="question1" id="wrong">Paris</input>
    <input type="radio" name="question1" id="wrong">Tokyo</input>

 <br><br>
     <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Answers" onClick="gradeit()"></input>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: How does `checkCookie` check a cookie?

Comment: By the eventlistener at the bottom where var elem is my submit button

Comment: Just because you have a `click` Event doesn't mean that it really checks a cookie.

Comment: Right, but that's also the part that is currently working.  The click calls the check cookie which then sends the addToCookie parameters to the addToCookie function (at least I think) .

Answer (score 0):

I just got it to work by modifying my gradeit() function this way:

```
function gradeit(){
var ans = "";
if(document.getElementById('correctOne').checked)
    {
      //document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Q1 - Correct";
      right++;
      ans ="Right";
      addToCookie("Q1 - ", ans);
    }
    else {
        ans ="Wrong";
        addToCookie("Q1 - ", ans);
        }
}
```